# Is the Green-Tao theorem a consequence of the Euler's theorem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

The Erdős-Turán conjecture states that

> If $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is such that
>   $$ \sum_{n\in A} \frac{1}{n} = \infty,$$
>   then $A$ contains arithmetic progressions of any given length.

I'm interest when $A$ is the set of all prime number . In this case, we know that, via Euler's theorem,
$$ \sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p} = \infty.$$

So we have the Green-Tao Theorem:

> The sequence of prime numbers contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions.

Is the Green-Tao theorem a consequence of the Euler's theorem? In other words, in the proof of the Green-Tao theorem is used the Euler's theorem?

Comment: Yes, Green-Tao conjecture follows from Euler's theorem conditionally on Erdos-Turan. But remember that Erdos-Turan conjecture is yet an open problem in CNT, so we really don't know if it is even true (though I bet it is!)

Comment: The special case of 3-term arithmetic progressions was only recently proven by Bloom and Sisask: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.03528.  This can be justifiably called the "easiest" case, since 3-APs are controlled by Fourier analysis that is very well-developed, whereas we now know that higher-order analysis is essential to understanding longer progressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terence Tao has a paper on his web site

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/gy-corr.dvi

explaining that the only information about prime numbers needed for the Green-Tao proof is that $\zeta(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$.

That behavior of zeta is equivalent to the "prime zeta function" $\sum \frac{1}{p^s}$ having a logarithmic singularity at the same point, so that $\sum \frac{1}{p^s} - \log (\frac{1}{s-1})$ is analytic near $s=1$.   This is slightly more than divergence of $\sum \frac {1}{p}$, but it can be proved by the same method as Euler's proof of the divergence.

A loose interpretation of this is that in many places in the Green-Tao paper, natural density assumptions can (probably) be replaced by weaker statements about Dirichlet density.